# java application as windows server 2016 service not starting when installed via powershell

Tags: java, windows, powershell, service

we're moving a java application from an old server to a new server running Windows Server 2016 - 
Services were installed via powershell but dont go to "Running" state. Service/s is/are always in the "Starting" State  .. 
tried increasing the timeout in the registry to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
set ServicesPipeTimeout to 10 mts (600000ms) .. but still at the same state. 
Is there any other registry setting that can be tried ? 
or a way of installing besides powershell that might be useful. 
Does it require a OS fix ?
I get the error 1053 - error - The service did not respond to a start or control request in a timely fashion - right now on attempting to start the service.

Comment: Likely an issue with Java versions/security settings not letting the service start properly. Look into the Application logs to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Check the application event log, it will usually provide you with an error message.

Comment: The application logs/event logs aren't being updated. Is there app-server log that can be looked into ? .. (just like tomcat/websphere/weblogic logs )